# Android Jetpack Compose Release mode publish downloaded but not installed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, apk

I started developing an application with Kotlin Jetpack Compose in Android Studio. After designing and coding the user interfaces of the application, I created the raw APK file and installed it on an Android device, and I was able to download and install it successfully. However, after I started using modules like Room and Hilt within the application to enable form functionalities, I created a new APK file for testing purposes and tried to install it on the Android device again. Unfortunately, I can download it, but I cannot install it.

In an attempt to troubleshoot the issue, I removed the Room and Hilt modules one by one and tried to test the installation process by creating and installing new APK files. However, even if I go back to the state before installing these modules, I still cannot install my APK file. I have been unable to identify where I made a mistake, and since I cannot inspect the APK while installing it on the active device, I'm unable to determine the cause of the problem.

APK build upload to device and download is ok but no installation

Comment: I'm not sure, but did your deinstalled the other version? If not, do it and try to install downloaded version.

Comment: I did it every new apk before upload